# How to propogate information to other classes?

Tags: oop, reference

**Preface**

I have a generalized question about how to deal with two separate classes that need information from one of the two. Let's suppose we have 2 classes, **A**, and **B**. Class **A** will be the class that a client interacts with. For a simple case, let's also say that class **A** is a generalized script that gives something health, and class **B** is a hitbox script. Class **A** has two variables, a numeric health and a Boolean for death. Class **B** has a single Boolean for if a hitbox can attack. I will outline these classes in C#.

**Class A**

```
public class A{

   double health = 100;
   bool dead = false;

   public void damage(double amount){
      health -= amount;     
      if(health <= 0){
         health = 0;
         dead = true;
         //code to run after death...
      }
   }

}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B{

   bool canHit = true;

   void Hit(){
      //do some hit code here...
   }   
}
```

Now, lets say that these two classes must work together since they are attached to a single player/enemy. In order for the hitbox class to know that it cannot hit anymore, it must know that it is dead; This is where my question comes into play.

**Question**

How should I let class **B** know that it is dead, and which way is the best way to do this?

I already know multiple ways to do this, but I would like some more insight on if there is a correct way and why it would be correct over others. Here are some of my solutions:

**Solution 1**

Class **A** has a reference to class **B**, and there is a function within class **B** that switches the 'canHit' boolean to 'false'. This function is called when the player dies.

**Solution 2**

Class **B** has a reference to class **A**. Whenever the hitbox wants to hit, it checks if class **A** is dead.

I'm mostly trying to figure out where I should have the reference and how the check should be performed. In this scenario, I believe **Solution 1** to be superior because the death is triggered once, and anything that must be halted due to death can just be referenced and deactivated all from class **A**, whereas **solution 2** must check repeatedly whether it can hit or not.

Again, this is just a specific use-case, but I would like some insight on where references should be and how to change classes' variables based on occurrences in other classes. Thanks!

Comment: I would remove the "can only hit if alive" logic from class B and instead put that logic in whatever class is actually calling hit()

Answer (score 0):

Follow the single responsibility principle. I'm going to assume that class B is a hitbox and class A is the player.

The player has health and a hitbox. The player can only hit if they're alive. The hitbox itself has no concept of dead or alive. Presumably, it only cares about its position versus its target's position. Therefore, the player should perform their own check when hitting, as opposed to passing off that conditional to the hitbox.

In the principle of single responsibility means that if a class doesn't need to do something, then it shouldn't. The hitbox presumably can still operate if the player is dead. It's whether or not the player is allowed to hit anything that's the issue. In that case, it is the player's responsibility to figure that out, not the hitbox's.

Comment: So would you say that Solution 1 would be better in this case?